# Changing background image of all my forms at the same time with a click of a button

Tags: c#, winforms, background-image

i would like to change the background image with a click of a button but
the background image property does not show when i put in form. is there anyway to do this?

Comment: You need global instances of all your forms to do that. Hope you're not doing it by `Form1 form1=new Form1(); form1.BackgroundImage=Image`

Comment: Please provide a little bit of code to clear things up a bit.

Answer (score 0):

put this code on your onclick()

```
form.BackgroundImage = image;
form1.BackgroundImage = image;
```

etc

just add which forms you want to change

Comment: sry but this does not help at all as i just said its property does not appear

Comment: My guess is that you lack some namespace or parameters to be declared in your code if the BackgroundImage property is not showing

Comment: @Revo Try Declaring a Theme for your application Using Enums,its  what i did in my app a while back and it worked like a charm.